# WPF Textwrapping trigger on ListView IsSelected state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, word-wrap

I am making a xaml app that has a listview. When the text is long, I am using textTrimming to shorten it but when the user clicks on the item I want the TextWrapping attribute to change from nowrap to wrap.
Here is what I have so far:

```
<Listview>
 <Listview.View>
   <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock x:Name="WordWrap" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
 </Listview.View>
</Listview>
```

I have a seperate overrides file with styles in it, that is setting other control template triggers and data triggers and here is what I tried there:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=WordWrap}" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
  </DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Gridview>
```

I get this error: *The member "TextWrapping" is not recognized or accessible.*

Let me know any solutions or fixes please! Still very new to xaml and WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBlock controls do not have an IsSelected property so your DataTrigger will never happen as is. IsSelected is a property on the containing ListViewItem so you can change your Trigger binding to that using RelativeSource. For Example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="WordWrap" Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Also, in order to change a property in a trigger, it cannot be hard coded in the element properties so move the original TextWrapping to within the Style as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After you close your textblock tag before you close the datatemplate try adding your trigger code there, except change it to  instead of style.

Comment: I just tried that and I still got the same error - The member "TextWrapping" is not recognized or accessible. As well as a new error - The property "IsSelected" was not found in type "Textblock".